# How do I hide the text in the terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

When I run the program, the terminal shows:

```
PS C:\Users\13028\Desktop\Coding> python -u "c:\Users\13028\Desktop\Coding\Practice.py"
```

before the output. I would rather the terminal look clean and only display the output of the function. I tried searching for solutions but cant find anything that works. I tried changing the .json file in settings, tried switching to output but then user input doesn't work.

Comment: It's called "terminal" for a reason. This is how your application/script/whatever is run from the terminal. It isn't called output.

Comment: How do you "run" this command? I would run a command, by typing it into the terminal, and in this case I of course want to see what I typed. If you are using some fancy VSC feature to run a command using some hotkey, I guess it depends on the way you configure this, whether or not the command will be displayed. In this case, your question is not suitable for stackoverflow, but would make sense to be asked on i.e. [su].